# Set focus on text box that is in array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to validate my inputs.  Each text box input is put into an array strExamAnswer(). As my user inputs A, B, C, or D I need to validate they are entering acceptable inputs.  I have the validation correct but I want the incorrect text box to gain focus after validation catches the incorrect input. How can I get the focus on the said text box using a loop that is checking each input in the array?

```
Private Sub Validatation(ByVal intIndex As Integer)
    Dim strA As String = "A"
    Dim strB As String = "B"
    Dim strC As String = "C"
    Dim strD As String = "D"


    For i = 0 To 19
        If strExamAnswer(i) = strA Then
            blnOk = True
        ElseIf strExamAnswer(i) = strB Then
            blnOk = True
        ElseIf strExamAnswer(i) = strC Then
            blnOk = True
        ElseIf strExamAnswer(i) = strD Then
            blnOk = True
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter A, B, C, D for Answer " & strQuestion(i))
            blnOk = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    blnOk = True

End Sub
```

So when this code kicks one of the questions back how do I tell it to focus on that specific text box in the array it is kicking out as invalid?  Is there even a way to do this in a loop using an array.  I would rather keep in a loop to limit amount of code. I could set up in a Case I just rather not.

Comment: Rather than a sub that should be a Function returning a boolean.  Global vars cause bugs. You dont need variables for A B C D, you *can* use literals: `If strExamAnswer(i) = "A" Then...`, but you can also check for ABCD at once:  `If validLetters.Contains(someTextBox.Text) Then...`, to make it case insensitive, expand `validLetters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array is named txtInput and has the same dimensions as strExamAnswer.

```
txtInput(i).Focus()
```

Comment: The array that is has the text boxes is strExamAnswer() that holds the input for each text box.  I tried using that strExamAnswer(i).Focus() and that didn't work.  Should I create another array to track each text box?

Comment: I suggest storing the entire textbox instead of just the answer in the array. Then you can both call Text(to get the answer) and Focus to set their focus.

Comment: So would that look like strInput() as String = {Ans1.text, Ans2.text, ect...}?

Comment: No, that would still be an array of strings. You want to create an array of TextBox objects (or whatever control you are using)

Comment: @BradWethington : You'd have to replace `String` with the type you need, and set the items to the actual control instead of its `Text` property: `Dim textBoxes As TextBox() = New TextBox() {Ans1, Ans2, ...}`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks! is the textBoxes the array? or is it TextBox()? Also do I still reference it as textBoxes(i).Focus()?

Comment: @BradWethington : `textBoxes` is the array's name. `TextBox()` is the variable type. The syntax for variables is: `[access modifier] Dim [variable name] As [variable type]`. :)

Comment: using textBoxes(i).Focus() is kicking back a null error?

Comment: @BradWethington : Check the `Autos` or `Locals` window in Visual Studio when the exception is thrown. What does it say is `Nothing`?

Comment: It shows {Length=20} in the Autos it shows nothing in the Locals.  When I run it gives the NullReferenceException was unhandled error. In the array it loads the text input into it, but nothing loads into textBoxes(i).Focus(). And also it is not focusing to text box with invalid input.  I have the textBoxes(i).Focus() after the messageBox.Show().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133302/discussion-between-visual-vincent-and-brad-wethington).